# How to enable input box upon click?

Tags: javascript

I have the following input:

```
<input type="text" value="John Smith" onClick="editUserName()" id="userNameInput" disabled>
```

It suppose to activate when a user clicks on it so it can be edited:

```
var userNameInput = document.getElementById("userNameInput");
function editUserName () {
    userNameInput.disabled = false;
}
```

I have tried both `disabled` and `disabled="disabled"`, nothing seems to effect it.
What's the issue here?

Comment: Try `userNameInput.removeAttribute('disabled');`

Comment: =false should work too - the problem is it is disabled

Comment: What's the point of disabling an input box if it's supposed to be editable anyway? This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: maybe to not send it to the server if it is not touched?

Comment: Well, its part of a "user profile" info display, its not supposed to be edited unless the user clicks on it. i know i could make it work another way but they seem a little more complicated... is there a way to make it work the way i attempted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the input element inside some div and catch the event and remove the disabled attribite.

```
<div onClick="editUserName()">
 <input type="text" value="John Smith" id="userNameInput" disabled>
</div>

var userNameInput = document.getElementById("userNameInput");
function editUserName () {
   userNameInput.removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/27Syr/644/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is it is disabled

Try onmouseover

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just remove the attribute as well:

```
userNameInput.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

I believe when you set the disabled attribute to 'disabled', it will just keep it disabled.

Comment: only in an event that is actually executed

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `disabled` attribute, at least in some browsers, prevents *any* user interaction with the element at all. This means that neither the `click` nor `mouseover` events will register in those browsers. What you could do to fix this is to create your own class that mimics the `disabled` styles, so that the events are still triggered.

I've made a **[demo](http://jsbin.com/oCoWoBi/1/)** of an example that would work.